# In M2.3.1 is elastic search required?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3.1

in Magento 2.3.1 MySQL search will not work at all? We are on a hosted solution (siteground) and do not have the rights to install something like elasticsearch. Does this mean we will NOT have ANY search capabilities? What options would I have aside from getting a dedicated host?

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

based on official documentation mysql 5.6, 5.7 supported on 2.3.x